# How to assign value to a decorated property in parent class constructor?

Tags: typescript, class, constructor, decorator, assign

I have a User class that has a decorated property "name". I am trying to initialize this property in parent class (Base) constructor using Object.assign but the value is "undefined". When I remove the decorator then the property is initialized with a correct value. See code below - I use typescript version 5.4.2.

Could anyone help me out please? Is there any way how to make this work?

Thanks.

```
// test.ts
(Symbol as any).metadata ??= Symbol("Symbol.metadata") // Polyfill

function Value(value: string) {
    return (_target: any, context: ClassFieldDecoratorContext) => {
        context.metadata![context.name] = value
    }
}

class Base {
    constructor(data: any) {
        Object.assign(this, data)
    }
}

interface IUser {
    id?: string
    name?: string
}

class User extends Base implements IUser {
    id?: string

    constructor(data: IUser) {
        super(data)
    }

    @Value("test")
    name?: string
}

const data = {
    id: "1",
    name: "John Doe"
}

const user = new User(data)
// user.id is 1
// user.name is undefined
```

Comment: This is [ms/TS#56000](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/56000), a TS bug with ES decorators when [`--useDefineForClassFields`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#the-usedefineforclassfields-flag-and-the-declare-property-modifier) is off. Keep in mind that in the future, `--useDefinedForClassFields` will be the default behavior, meaning that eventually you will not be able to silently inherit class fields from parents; they will become `undefined` for everyone. Does that fully address the q? If so I'll write an a; if not, what's missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is considered a bug in TypeScript, reported at [microsoft/TypeScript#56000](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/56000).

This is a bit of fallout from the fact that [public class fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Public_class_fields) as implemented in modern JavaScript differs semantically from how TypeScript originally implemented them. In particular, if you declare a class field in a JavaScript subclass, that field will be initialized as `undefined` and *not* automatically inherited from the superclass. If you want TypeScript to behave to conform with JavaScript, you need to enable [the `--useDefineForClassField` flag](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#the-usedefineforclassfields-flag-and-the-declare-property-modifier).  And you probably ultimately *do* want to do that, since that's how things work going forward.

Additionally, we know that [decorators](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-5-0.html#decorators) are different from how TypeScript originally thought they would be (notice a theme here?) so there's a new implementation in TypeScript 5.0 and above.

It looks like the [downleveling](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html#downleveling) for JavaScript decorators in TypeScript always acts as if `--useDefineForClassField` is enabled. So even when you have the flag off, decorated fields will suddenly act like the flag is on, giving you the `undefined` behavior you're seeing here.

It's a bug and probably will be fixed, but... ultimately if you're using JS decorators you should plan to use JS class fields as well, because as soon as you start targeting a JS runtime that implements JS decorators, they will also implement JS class fields. Any attempt to maintain new decorators with old fields is probably going to eventually break.